# SQL 2008 + IIS Application Pool: Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the user's local application data path

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis-7.5, sql-server-2008-r2

I´m having trouble connecting to SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Northwind database using ApplicationPoolIdentity in IIS 7.5, resulting in the following error message:

`Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the user's local application data path. The connection will be closed.`

notes:

- I´m using Windows 7/VS 2010/IIS 7.5/SQL Server 2008 R2 Express (all in the same machine).
- my site is using "ASP.NET v4.0" application pool;
- ASP.NET v4.0 application pool is using ApplicationPoolIdentity as Identity;
- the SQL Server 2008 R2 express has the Login "IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NETv4.0" with the server role sysadmin granted;
- the Northwind database has the user "IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0"    configured with the following permitions: db_accessadmin, db_backupoperator, db_datareader, db_datawriter, db_ddladmin, db_securityadmin;
- the w3wp.exe process is running with the user "IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NETv4.0"
- I can see that the user profile folder is created (C:\Users\ASP.NET v4.0);
- the same problem occurs using the application pool "DefaultAppPool".

If I change the ApplicationPoolIdentity user to another user that has rights to access the database it works.

**Additional informations:**

connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="NorthwindEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/NorthwindModel.csdl|res://*/NorthwindModel.ssdl|res://*/NorthwindModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=NOTEBOOK\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Could anyone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Can you post your connection string (make sure you XXXX out any passwords).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use SQL Server Express's ["user instancing"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143684.aspx) feature, i.e. your connection string looks like:

```
AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|xxxxxx.mdf;User Instance=true
```

This won't work for `ApplicationPoolIdentity` accounts in IIS7.5. For more information see this MS Knowledgebase article:

> [Problems with SQL Server Express user instancing and ASP.net Web Application Projects](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2002980)
>
> Web applications built with Visual Studio 2005, Visual Studio 2008, or
>   Visual Studio 2010 and that rely on user instancing with either SQL
>   Server Express 2005 or SQL Server Express 2008 do not work with the
>   new application pool identity.  These products were developed and
>   tested against application pools running with the older NETWORK
>   SERVICE account.

Also Microsoft [discourage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143684.aspx) using this feature now:

> This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL
>   Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to
>   modify applications that currently use this feature.

If you've not already done so, I would [attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794.aspx) the database to SQL Express and use a regular SQL connection string instead, just like you'd do in a production environment. You may need to enable TCP/IP for your SQL Express instance using the SQL Server Configuration Manager if it's not already enabled:

[image]

And ensure that port 1433 is configured as well on the next tab of that dialogue.

Comment: thanks for your reply but the weird is that I´m not using user instance (see the additional informations in my original post), nor attaching a database (mdf file). I´m using a regular connection string with the entity framework.

Comment: the problem has been solved. The cause is that although I´m not using a sql user instance to the main database (northwind) I do to the aspnetdb. I had not realized that. So, I just attached the aspnetdb to the sql express and everything was fine. Thanks.

Comment: @rperson - ah ha! That ASPNETDB connection string is a bit sneaky. :)